# Listing all monotone increasing binary digits

Tags: list-manipulation, binary, digits

For $n=5$, I have $32$ binary digits and for this there are $2^{32}$ combinations. Out of this many, the interesting ones (i.e., the ones that have monotone increasing binary digits) are only about "$2111$". I know how these can be found very easily but I am missing Mathematica knowledge. Therefore I cannot complete my program.

First I need to seperate these $32$ bits according to Pascals triangle numbers. Since $n=5$, these numbers are $1,5,10,10,5,1$. Their sum is $32$ and I separate the digits accordingly. My list is as follows:

```
List={

{0|00000|0000000000|0000000000|00000|0}

... those who satisfy the rule below

{1|11111|1111111111|1111111111|11111|1}}
```

From right to the left I start with the 5 bits and take all possible combinations:

```
|00000|--> 00001,00010,00011...11111
```

This says I have the following ones in the list

```
{0|00000|0000000000|0000000000|00001|1,    
0|00000|0000000000|0000000000|00010|1,   
0|00000|0000000000|0000000000|00011|1,...,      
0|00000|0000000000|0000000000|11111|1}
```

Then I go left via keeping |11111|1 as fixed. Now I have $10$ digits and the following are the elements of the list

```
{0|00000|0000000000|0000000001|11111|1,    
0|00000|0000000000|0000000010|11111|1,   
0|00000|0000000000|0000000011|11111|1,...,      
0|00000|0000000000|1111111111|11111|1}
```

Then, I do the same thing again but fixing |1111111111|11111|1. Then the followings are the elements of the  set:

```
{0|00000|0000000000|1111111111|11111|1,    
0|00000|0000000001|1111111111|11111|1,   
0|00000|0000000010|1111111111|11111|1,...,      
0|00000|1111111111|1111111111|11111|1}
```

Again the same thing and we are done:

```
{0|00001|1111111111|1111111111|11111|1,    
0|00010|1111111111|1111111111|11111|1,   
0|00011|1111111111|1111111111|11111|1,...,      
0|11111|1111111111|1111111111|11111|1}
```

So in total there are $2^5$ numbers from the first stage, From the other two stages we have $2^{10}-1$ for each and for the last stage $2^5-1$ numbers. We also have all zeros and all ones and if I calculated correctly there are $2111$ of them. I used the character "|" for separation. The final list should look like

```
List={{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},....,{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}}
```

I only have the following code part:

```
IntegerDigits[2, 2, 5]
{0, 0, 0, 1, 0}

IntegerDigits[2, 2, 10]
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}
```

Using this code in a 'for loop'  I can obtain such combinations but I must concatenate these to the previous bits which are all zeros and all subsequent bits which are all 1s. This is what I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to make use of [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples):

```
monotoneTuples[b_, m_, e_] := Rest @ Tuples@Join[
    ConstantArray[{0}, b],
    ConstantArray[{0,1}, m],
    ConstantArray[{1}, e]
]
```

`monotoneTuples` will create your partitioned set. For example:

```
Column @ monotoneTuples[5, 3, 1] //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  \{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1\} \\
> \end{array}$

Then, you can join each of these sets:

```
res = Join[
    monotoneTuples[31,1,0],
    monotoneTuples[26,5,1],
    monotoneTuples[16,10,6],
    monotoneTuples[6,10,16],
    monotoneTuples[1,5,26],
    monotoneTuples[0,1,31]
];
res //Length
```

> 2110

**Addendum**

For memory reasons, it makes sense to create a list of integers instead of a list of bit vectors, especially if you will be creating a lot of them. So, an alternative is:

```
monotoneIntegers[list_] := With[{a = Accumulate[Prepend[0] @ Most @ Reverse @ list]},
    Prepend[0][Join @@ (Range[2, 2^Reverse@list] 2^a - 1)]
]
```

For example, compare:

```
integers = monotoneIntegers[{1,3,2}]
bitvectors = IntegerDigits[%, 2, 6]
```

> {0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 63}
>
> {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
>     1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0,
>      1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 
>     1, 1, 1, 1}}

The memory usage of the integers is much less:

```
ByteCount @ integers
ByteCount @ bitvectors
```

> 200
>
> 1968

and the disparity increases with more bits.

Comment: thats really an excellent way.  Just the all zero sequence is missing. then the total number will be also $2111$.

Comment: monotoneTuples[0, 31, 1] this is killing my mathematica)

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören It takes 550GB to store a 2^31 by 32 array of integers, so that's why your computer is unhappy.

Comment: maybe it could be nicer if your comment would be told to me by Mathematica itself?

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[monotoneDigits]
monotoneDigits = Module[{a = Accumulate[Binomial[#, Range[-1, #]]]},
 Join[{ConstantArray[0, 2^#]}, 
  IntegerDigits[Join@@Range[2^Most[1 + a] - 1, 2^Rest[a] - 1, 2^Most[a]], 2, 2^#]]]&;

Length @ monotoneDigits[5]
```

> 2111

```
Rest @ monotoneDigits[5] == res (* res from Carl's answer *)
```

> True

```
Length /@ (monotoneDigits /@ Range[2, 6])
```

> {6, 17, 96, 2111, 1114238}

```
monotoneDigits2[3] // Column // TeXForm
```

> $\small\begin{array}{l}
>  \{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1\} \\
>  \{0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1\} \\
>  \{0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1\} \\
>  \{0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1\} \\
>  \{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1\} \\
>  \{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1\} \\
> \end{array}$

**Update:** An alternative using `Tuples` in combination with `PadLeft` and `PadRight`:

```
ClearAll[paddedTuples , monotoneDigits2]
paddedTuples[t_][{m_, n_}] := PadLeft[PadRight[Rest@Tuples[{0, 1}, m], 
  {Automatic, n}, 1], {Automatic, t}] 

monotoneDigits2 = Module[{a = Transpose[{#, Accumulate@#}& @ Binomial[#, Range[0, #]]]}, 
   Join @@ (paddedTuples[2^#] /@ a)]&;

monotoneDigits2[5] == res
```

> True

Comment: Great job as always..